# How to prevent some form's fields from being submitted

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form and an `onBlur` listener on each field. This listener registers those fields that a user at some moment edited or at least put cursor on. Before I submit my form I loop through all fields of the form and if I see that a particular field is not among those registered by my listener, then I destroy it. After that I submit the form. The problem is, it seems as if `destroy` operation is asynchronous in some sense. By this I mean that even though a particular field was not registered there is still some chance that it can be submitted. Sometimes, I see that it happens, sometimes - not. And indeed it depenends on a number of fields. So, I need some more stable solution of excluding fields from a form. Now, this kind of solution

```
...loop through fields
    if(bad_field) field.destroy();
... end of loop
form.getForm().submit({
...
})
```

does not work in a stable manner.

Comment: can you share the code for submitting the form so that we can know what you are doing ?

Comment: I just submit my form with post method to a particular url. General stuff. I guess, the solution is somewhere before the submission process. The whole issue is how to exclude a field from a form beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to disable them or to collect values manually.

Comment: I now set `name` attribute to `null` and it works. Actually, heavy `destroy` function was not a good choice

Comment: I ment to use `setDisable(true)` on the fields